# Jenkin Pipeline Git Push via Windows Agent Node

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

So I have the following scenario:

Jenkin Primary: Red Hat 7
Jenkin Agent Node: Windows Server 2019

Using the Windows Agent Node, I am trying to checkout a repository, add / update changes, and commit and push back to GitHub.

I got check out and commit working correctly but having issue with pushing back to GitHub. I've tried a few method but none seem to work.

**Pipeline:**

```
def NodeLabel = 'windows'
//def CustomWorkSpace = "C:/JenkinsWorkspace/${env.JOB_BASE_NAME}"
def CustomWorkSpace = "C:/Work"

// Organization
def OrganizationName = [
    'organization1',
    'organization2'
]

// Solution
def SolutionMap = [
    SolutionA: [
        SolutionName: 'SolutionA',
        RequiredVersion: '1.0.0.0',
        UnpackedFileFolder: 'FolderA/ConfigurationA/SolutionA'
    ]
]

pipeline {
    agent {
        node {
            <Node Stuff...>
        }
    }

    environment {
        RELEASE_NAME = 'Release-0'
        SOURCE_DIRECTORY = 'Source'
    }

    parameters {
        <Parameter...>
    }

    stages {
        // Check Out Repository
        stage('Check Out Repository') {
            steps {
                checkout([
                    $class: 'GitSCM',
                    branches: [
                        [name: '*/development']
                    ],
                    doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
                    extensions: [
                        [$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory',
                            relativeTargetDir: SOURCE_DIRECTORY],
                        [$class: 'LocalBranch',
                            localBranch: RELEASE_NAME],
                        [$class: 'UserIdentity',
                            email: '<Email>',
                            name: '<Name>'],
                        [$class: 'CleanBeforeCheckout',
                            deleteUntrackedNestedRepositories: true]
                    ],
                    submoduleCfg: [],
                    userRemoteConfigs: [
                        [credentialsId: '<Credential>',
                            url: '<URL>']
                    ]
                ])
            }
        }

        // Solution
        stage('Solution') {
            steps {
                script {
                    SolutionMap.each { Solution ->
                        <Some Work...>

                        // Git Commit Solution Source Code
                        stage("Git Commit Solution: ${Solution.key}") {
                            dir(SOURCE_DIRECTORY) {
                                powershell(script: """
                                git config core.fileMode false
                                git config core.autocrlf false
                                git add --all
                                git commit --allow-empty --message="Commit ${Solution.value.SolutionName} version ${Solution.value.RequiredVersion}"
                                """)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Git
        stage('Git Push') {
            steps {
                dir(SOURCE_DIRECTORY) {
                    powershell(script: """
                    Write-Host User Profile: ${USERPROFILE}
                    Write-Host Release Name: ${RELEASE_NAME}
                    git push origin ${RELEASE_NAME}
                    """)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Few things I tried:

If I just try

```
git push origin ${RELEASE_NAME}
```

or

```
powershell(script: """ssh-add ${USERPROFILE}/.ssh/id_rsa""")
powershell(script: """git push origin ${RELEASE_NAME}""")
```

I will get:

```
powershell.exe : Could not create directory '/work/jenkins/latest/.ssh'.
At C:\Work\Source@tmp\durable-cfdcf986\powershellWrapper.ps1:3 char:1
+ & powershell -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Comm ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Could not creat...s/latest/.ssh'.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

If I were to try a subshell method:

```
ssh-agent bash -c 'ssh-add ${USERPROFILE}/.ssh/id_rsa; git push origin ${RELEASE_NAME}'
```

It executes, but doesn't seem to do anything or push anything.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do the powershell command work on the node without jenkins?

Comment: hi @Holleoman, yes, it works fine if I just execute the commands on the machine itself

Comment: just FYI, my current work around is to create a separate job, and execute the job from the pipeline 

Comment: Maybe use a git plugin which can checkout and commit. Then its easier to debug.

Comment: yes, that was my work around, which is the create a separate job to run the Git, but I don't understand why it doesn't work in the declarative pipeline...?